# Error: Composition: Missing stories.json version with https://storybook.js.org/

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I am doing this tutorial :https://storybook.js.org/tutorials/ui-testing-handbook/react/en/visual-testing/
When I ran this code

```
import React from 'react';
import { Task } from './Task';

export default {
  component: Task,
  title: 'Task',
  argTypes: {
    onArchiveTask: { action: 'onArchiveTask' },
    onTogglePinTask: { action: 'onTogglePinTask' },
    onEditTitle: { action: 'onEditTitle' },
  },
};

const Template = (args) => <Task {...args} />;

export const Default = Template.bind({});
Default.args = {
  task: {
    id: '1',
    title: 'Buy milk',
    state: 'TASK_INBOX',
  },
};
```

All the code and story book ran fine . But when I ran this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Task } from './Task';

export default {
  component: Task,
  title: 'Task',
  argTypes: {
    onArchiveTask: { action: 'onArchiveTask' },
    onTogglePinTask: { action: 'onTogglePinTask' },
    onEditTitle: { action: 'onEditTitle' },
  },
};

const Template = (args) => <Task {...args} />;

export const Default = Template.bind({});
Default.args = {
  task: {
    id: '1',
    title: 'Buy milk',
    state: 'TASK_INBOX',
  },
};

export const Pinned = Template.bind({});
Pinned.args = {
  task: {
    id: '2',
    title: 'QA dropdown',
    state: 'TASK_PINNED',
  },
};

export const Archived = Template.bind({});
Archived.args = {
  task: {
    id: '3',
    title: 'Write schema for account menu',
    state: 'TASK_ARCHIVED',
  },
};
```

The browser show me this error :

```
Couldn't find any stories in your Storybook.
```

and in the console said

````
Unexpected error while loading ./components/Task.stories.js: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\storybook\ui-testing-guide-code\src\components\Task.stories.js: Missing initializer in const declaration. (29:19)```
Any idea why this is happening?
````

Comment: The story is there because ran with the first code. But the second code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess was some issue with Babel . I decided to do the remove and add.

```
yarn remove --dev babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env webpack
yarn add --dev babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env webpack
```

Solved the issue.